# Download a Package within an Octopus Step

Tags: octopus-deploy

I have an Octopus Deployment Project in which I am doing some changes in settings files like appsettings.json. So in different steps lots of changes been done. So at the end I am deploying it into Azure. But my question is, is there is any way to download a package just before pushing into Azure.

I know there are option to download package from Library. But those are not processed. So I need the altered package to be download.

Answer (score 1):

How are you deploying to Azure? Is it an Azure Web App? In a lot of steps, you can use custom deployment scripts and variable substitution to update the package prior to its installation.

For example, in the Deploy an Azure Web App step, you can click on **Configure Features** and enable Custom Deployment Scripts and [JSON Configuration Variables](https://octopus.com/docs/deployment-process/configuration-features/structured-configuration-variables-feature).

[image: step features]